# Exception when using headless Chrome to take screenshot of a video

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to take screenshots of a video using Selenium and Java. It works fine when I use headed Chrome, but when I want to make it headless a "java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster" is thrown in

```
    getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);
```

Here's the code:

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

    // Get URL and find image
    driver.get("https://www.webcamtaxi.com/en/netherlands/north-holland/purmerend-traffic-cam.html");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    while (true) {
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("insideCam"));

        // Get entire page screenshot
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        BufferedImage fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

        // Get the location of element on the page
        Point point = ele.getLocation();

        // Get width and height of the element
        int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
        int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

        // Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
        BufferedImage eleScreenshot = fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);
        ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
    }
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way around this. I took over a test suite that was ran in headless browsers and when I attempted to add screenshots for debugging all I was able to capture was black screens. Had to move to selenium grid and headed browsers on nodes to get screenshots.